# "Unable to access location" on 1st try. Works fine on 2nd try?

Tags: mount, bug-reporting, drive

I'm experiencing an odd issue with 18.04.01 LTS.

When I try to access two of my HDD's from the "Files" icon, I first get a message when I click the drive icon:

*"Unable to access location"*

I close the warning, click the icon again and the drive opens just fine. These are my only two HDDs and both have this issue. I have 3 SSD's (and numerous USB thumbdrives) that open just fine on the first try.

Is this a bug or do I need to change something? TIA.

Comment: How are you connecting the hard drives? SATA? USB? SATA to USB? Using some kind of Adapter or dock? Are these external or internal hard drives?

Comment: Both are internal Sata-3 HDD drives.

Comment: Has this always been the case or has it just started happening recently? Potentially with an update of some kind?